# How do I turn off this suggestion when holding the L key?

Tags: keyboard

When holding the lowercase l key of my keyboard, I got a suggestion of a not-or simple. Is it possible to turn this off?

[image]

Comment: It’s called *Pressandhold*.  To turn it off, try this command `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`. (Sorry, I can’t test at the moment).  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That's L with stroke, used mainly in Polish

Comment: @Allan Hi Allan! That works for me. A little about the problem background as feedback if you're interested: I was trying a cool terminal emulator called Warp, and I thought this is a feature of it. It seems that Apple re-enabled this option after my recent updates... (I'm at Ventura 13.4)

Comment: Glad it worked!

Comment: @Raining Unrelated... don't use Warp without reading their [privacy](https://docs.warp.dev/getting-started/privacy) policy.  Then don't use it at all.

Comment: @MarcWilson: Thanks for your advice. Could you provide the trait(s) of software one should never use, for example why we should use Warp? I will read their policy in the meanwhile for sure!

Answer (score 4):

This problem is solved by @Allan in the comment section of my OP. In short:

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

and then either log-out or restart your computer.
This is something I disabled many years ago when I bought
my macbook air. I think either myself or they (since I accepted two updates of macOS recently) enable this option back for some reason.

Why there isn't an user interface to turn off it? I don't know...

Comment: Note that this won't take effect in any particular application until it's restarted. Probably simplest to logout and back in.

Comment: @Barmar: You're right. I missed that part. just updated it!